# How to change uiimageview content mode at runtime?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, contentmode

I have a UIViewController with an UIImageView, if I tap the screen, i want the UIImageView to change its contentMode. But I found out that this is not working with some images, mainly those from AVCaptureSession.

**Screenshots:**
*Aspect fill*

[image]

*Aspect fit*

[image]

I also found out that it's working fine when I change device orientation to landscape and back. But when I tap the screen is not working again.

*Aspect fit after changed orientation to landscape and back (this is how I want it to look everytime in aspect fit)*

[image]

**My code:**

**CameraController:**

```
class CameraController: UIViewController {

private var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
private var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice!
private var capturePhotoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
private var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupCaptureSession()
    setupCaptureDevice()
    setupInputAndOutput()
    setupPreviewLayer()
    startCaptureSession()

    setupLayout()
}

private func setupCaptureSession() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
}

private func setupCaptureDevice() {
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices.first else { return }

    captureDevice = device
}

private func setupInputAndOutput() {
    do {
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)

        let captureSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])
        capturePhotoOutput.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([captureSettings], completionHandler: nil)
        captureSession.addOutput(capturePhotoOutput)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

private func setupPreviewLayer() {
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
    previewLayer.frame = view.frame
    view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
}

private func startCaptureSession() {
    captureSession.startRunning()
}

private func setupLayout() {
    let captureButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    captureButton.backgroundColor = .white
    captureButton.layer.cornerRadius = 22
    captureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didPressCaptureButton), for: .touchUpInside)
    captureButton.center.x = view.center.x
    captureButton.center.y = view.frame.height - 50
    view.addSubview(captureButton)
}

@objc private func didPressCaptureButton() {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    capturePhotoOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}
}

extension CameraController: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else { return }
    guard let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else { return }

    print("Image size: ", image.size)

    let previewController = PreviewController()
    previewController.image = image
    present(previewController, animated: true, completion: {
        self.captureSession.stopRunning()
    })
}
}
```

**PreviewController:**

```
class PreviewController: UIViewController {

var imageView: UIImageView!
var image: UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupImageView()
}

func setupImageView() {
    imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    view.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.addConstraintsToFillSuperview()
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let contentMode: UIViewContentMode = imageView.contentMode == .scaleAspectFill ? .scaleAspectFit : .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.contentMode = contentMode
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank You!

Comment: Instead of changing the image view content mode, what if you replace the image view with another one?

Comment: try and call layoutSubViews() after you change the content mode.

Comment: `layoutSubviews()` is what you call when working *within* a `UIView`. But your code looks like it's from a `UIViewController`, so the correct method to call is `view.setNeedsLayout()`.

Comment: layoutSubview() nor view.setNeedsLayout() doesn't work :(

Comment: @matt Adding another UIImageView and changing its 'isHidden' property works. But it just doesn't feel like right way to do this.

Comment: On what basis do you say that? It feels a lot more right to me than trying to change the content mode. You might try changing the content mode and then saying `setNeedsDisplay`, but on the whole the notion of changing an image view's content mode when it is already displaying an image feels abhorrent. The fact that you feel you need to do that is itself a Bad Smell, in my view.

Comment: Also I've experienced some issues with UIImageView refreshing when their content or content mode changes; so maybe swapping image views is just the easiest way out.

Answer (score -1):

You can change ImageView `contentMode` on runtime with:

```
    self.imageView.contentMode = newContentMode
    self.imageView.setNeedsDisplay()
```